# How to test an Excel addin without installer

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel-addins

I'm working on an Excel addin, but every time they ask for a new change or fix, i have to make an installer and send it to them and that takes time.

Any advice how I can send them an update or copy the changes to their version?

Regards

Comment: You have to publish your add-in, there's no other way.

Comment: Thanks, all my hopes dies there. Regards